# Windows 8 sdk can not be setup in Win7?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

To experience the Windows 8 app developing,I downloaded the sdk of Windows 8 and tied to setup.

The error message show that this sdk could only be setup on the Pc of Os>=Windows 8.

Couldn't I do my windows 8 app developing in Windows 7?

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to develop `Windows Store Applications` in Windows 7.

[Getting started with Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx)

**Windows Phone 8**

[Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

> **System requirements**
>
> Supported operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro
>
> •◦Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
>
> •Hardware: ◦4 GB of free hard disk space
>   ◦4 GB RAM
>   ◦64-bit (x64) CPU
>
> •Windows Phone 8 Emulator:  ◦Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
>   ◦Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
>   If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

Comment: Hi Mayank,  I really want to know if i could develop windows phone 8 in win7?

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use Windows 8 to develop Windows 8 apps for the Windows Store.